# Transfer the block from right-sidebar to main content

Tags: php, magento, frontend, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

I am using magento 1.8.1 and i installed one extension i.e checkdelivery. but on frontend their block is shown in right-sidebar, but i don't want right-sidebar on that page. so how i transfer that block from right-sidebar to main content.

Their Phtml file:

```
    <div class="block block-list block-check-delivery">
<div class="block-title">
    <?php $blockLabel = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/block_title'); ?>
    <strong><span><?php echo $this->__($blockLabel) ?></span></strong>
</div>
<div class="block-content" >        
    <br>
        <input name="zipcode" size="17" type="text" id="zipcode" maxlength="10" class="input-text" placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Enter ZIP Code'); ?>"/>
        <button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('Check'); ?></span></button>
        <div id="delivery-message"></div>
        <?php $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html'); ?>
        <div id="delivery-html"><?php echo $defaultHtml ?></div>

    <br>        
</div>
```

and Ajax code:

```
  <script>
Event.observe('zip-check', 'click', function(event){
    new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
        method: "get",
        parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
             var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
             $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                 
             $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
             $('delivery-html').update(json.html);  
        }
    });
});
```

layout.xml

```
   <layout version="0.1.0">

<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="right" > 
        <block type="checkdelivery/checkdelivery" before="-" name="checkdelivery"> 
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="checkdelivery/general/active">
                <template>checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference> 
</catalog_product_view>
<catalog_product_view>
    <block type="checkdelivery/checkdelivery" before="-" name="checkdelivery"> 
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="checkdelivery/general/active">
            <template>checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml</template>
        </action> 
    </block>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: show us the relevant codes. Without that we cant help you out.. thanks

Comment: now i puts both phtml code and ajax code

Comment: show the layout xml file that is used by that extension. Sorry if that was not clear. phtml files will not help us to figure out the exact block

Comment: yeah, i put the layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your layout as follows

```
<catalog_product_view>
  <reference name="content">
    <block type="checkdelivery/checkdelivery" name="checkdelivery" as="checkdelivery"> 
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="checkdelivery/general/active">
            <template>checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml</template>
        </action> 
    </block>
  </reference>  
</catalog_product_view>
```

and call the block in product/view.phtml like as follows:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('checkdelivery')
```

Comment: hey, its work fine on localhost, but when i used same coading on server, its not display on frontend, why?

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside your `local.xml` file.

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <remove name="checkdelivery" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkdelivery/checkdelivery" name="checkdelivery">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="checkdelivery/general/active">
                    <template>checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Then call your block inside `view.phtml` like this.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkdelivery') ?>
```

Comment: you need to call your block in `view.phtml` file as pankaj pointed out.